# Upload to S3 killed with lots of files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm having an issue with a loop that requests the buffer object of an object in S3 from that objects URL, and the uploads that object to a different S3 bucket. I have a file uploader in Bubble.io that I found no way to easily configure to upload directly to S3, so I have the list of image urls posted to a server where I can get the images from those URLs and then upload them to my S3 bucket. This process was working fine with ~10 urls at a time, but gets killed by hundreds. I've tried implementing solutions having to do with async/await and promise, but those have failed – could they work with refactoring? Here is the code

```
    for (let i = 0; i <= imageList2.length; i++) {
     options = {
       uri: imageList0[i],
       encoding: null
     },
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log("failed to get image");
        console.log(error);
       
      } else {
        params = {
          Body: body,
          Key: booking_id4,
          Bucket: 'mybucket'
      };
      s3.upload({
        Bucket : 'mybucket', 
        Key: booking_id4, 
        Body: body
      }, 
      function (error, data) {
       if (error) {
         console.log("error downloading image to s3");
        } else {
         console.log("success uploading to s3");     
        }  
      })
    }
 })
}
```

This all is nested within the route the URLs get posted to. I've seen another person raise this issue in a post dating back 6 years (on GitHub) and they were told they could resolve it by passing something in their callback function. I'm fairly inexperienced so I couldn't really see how to implement that without an example. Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I tried a lot of different ways to get the content from bubble to s3 directly, as this is obviously very far from ideal. Had no luck, but if there exists a potential solution there I'm all ears.

Comment: `p-limit` is what you may want to take a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit

Comment: @Scaccoman I was able to build a solution and have been recreating what I had in bubble with Typescript + Node. The uploader component is still haunting me though, despite working in development the entire thing fails to compile in production, but only when this uploader component is imported into another component. I'm going to post a new question about this, in it people will be able to see the solution I came to.